# How to specify path to store data while developing google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing chrome extension which will download the data from currently requested url, but I am not able to store the file on any custom  path, data stores in download folder by default, but I want to store my data in custom path. Kindly give me solution on it.

```
    chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
function(details) {
    let fileUrl = details.url
        chrome.downloads.download({
            url: fileUrl
        })

},
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
["responseHeaders"]
```

);

Comment: Extensions can only download to the downloads directory, or its subdirectories.

Comment: How could I mention sudirectory to store the file, I tried but it didn't work in my case